# interactive report filter text is not getting translated in Oracle APEX Application translation

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a problem in french translation of an application. The application is translated completely fine, but when we run an Interactive Report, the string showing current filter is still in English, not in French. See the following screen shot
[image]

Is there a way that we can translate the string showing filter text (in this example "Running" and "Highlight Failed")? Can someone please help with this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Interactive Report and Interactive Grid settings are being set in the frontend rather than the backend where all the translation logic is located. Therefore, I don't think it is possible to do this with the standard APEX translation methods.

If you have a basic Report with only little customatization and you really need to translate these filters, I would suggest to create two Reports in the Backend, one for the english version, one for the french version, and use the language application item (usually `FSP_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE`) to display one or another.

If you have a complicated report with several private reports or heavy customization, I would advise against this solution and just use both language to name your Report settings like you did in your example.

Another option would be to use Javascript to rename the display filter. Try `$('.a-IG-controlsLabel[data-setting="highlight"]')` to select the appropriate items. However, it will be kind of hard to find the correct event handlers to trigger this at the right moment.